# In Unix, is it possible to give getops a range of values to expect?

Tags: unix, shell, getopt

Sorry if the title is confusing, but here's what I mean:

If I have a script that can accept several parameters, I'd use the getops command in order to more easily control script actions based on the parameters passed. However, lets say one of these parameters can be any number from 5 - 9, or whatever. Is there a way to tell getops that any number passed as command to the script between 5 and 9 should be taken as a single user-command?

My code so far is something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
args=`getopt -o abc: -- "$@"`
eval set -- "$args"
echo "After getopt"
for i in $args
do
 case "$i" in
    -c) shift;echo "flag c set to $1";shift;;
    -a) shift;echo "flag a set";;
    -b) shift;echo "flag b set";;
done
```

I want to see if I can do something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
args=`getopt -o ab[0-9]c: -- "$@"`
eval set -- "$args"
echo "After getopt"
for i in $args
do
 case "$i" in
    -c) shift;echo "flag c set to $1";shift;;
    -a) shift;echo "flag a set";;
    -b) shift;echo "flag b set";;
    -[0-9]) shift; echo $i;;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

No, at least not with the one I use (someone may have an enhanced one out there but it won't be standard anywhere).

For that particular case, it's probably okay to use:

```
args=`getopt -o ab0123456789c: -- "$@"`
```

although, for larger cases, that might be unwieldy.

Have you thought about not treating them as individual options? In other words, say they're debug levels for a logging procedure. Why could you not use:

```
args=`getopt -o abc:d: -- "$@"`
```

and specify them with `progname -b -d4` instead of `progname -b -4`?

Comment: That brace expansion doesn't do what you think it does:

` echo ab{0..9}c` => `ab0c ab1c ab2c ab3c ab4c ab5c ab6c ab7c ab8c ab9c`